# Is there any library to transform recorded video to certain aspect ratio(croping) in react native?

Tags: react-native, video-processing, react-native-camera

I am using RNCamera to record video along with react-native-video-helper library for trimming/compressing video. I want to record or transform recorded video like instagram to wide angle(not potrait mode). It's been almost a week I am looking for a solution but I could'nt find anything useful till yet. I have tried react-native-video-processing library as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out myself, posting answer to any one else struggling with the same scenario:
Go for ffmpeg, you can do almost every thing with this awesome tool, croping, merging, adding emoji's, text to video, triming, removing audio from video and so on.

[You can find test application for a quick startup along with the package as well](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ffmpeg)